# Update a single record in database CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am trying to update a single record of the database with the function "updateAll", and filtering by a single "id".

```php
$this->Factura->updateAll(
  array(
    'Factura.I_COBRADO' => $factura['Factura']['I_TOTAL'],
    'Factura.L_COBRADA' => 1,
    'Factura.FH_COBRO' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'Factura.S_FORMAPAGO' => 'tarjeta',
    'Factura.FK_FORMAPAGOCOBRO' => 41
  ),
  array(
    'Factura.PK_FACTURA' => $factura['Factura']['PK_FACTURA'])
  )
```

But I get this error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '15:10:55, `Factura`.`S_FORMAPAGO` = tarjeta, `Factura`.`FK_FORMAPAGOCOBRO` = 41 ' at line 1

> SQL Query: UPDATE `itramit_daily_desarrollo`.`facturas` AS `Factura` LEFT JOIN `itramit_daily_desarrollo`.`expedientes` AS `Expediente` ON (`Factura`.`FK_EXPEDIENTE` = `Expediente`.`PK_EXPEDIENTE`) LEFT JOIN `itramit_daily_desarrollo`.`expedientes` AS `ExpedienteFactura` ON (`Factura`.`FK_EXPEDIENTE` = `ExpedienteFactura`.`PK_EXPEDIENTE`) LEFT JOIN `itramit_daily_desarrollo`.`municipios` AS `Municipio` ON (`Factura`.`FK_MUNICIPIO` = `Municipio`.`PK_MUNICIPIO`) LEFT JOIN `itramit_daily_desarrollo`.`valoraciones` AS `Valoracione` ON (`Factura`.`FK_VALORACION` = `Valoracione`.`PK_VALORACION`) LEFT JOIN `itramit_daily_desarrollo`.`liquidaciones` AS `Liquidacione` ON (`Factura`.`FK_LIQUIDACION` = `Liquidacione`.`PK_LIQUIDACION`) LEFT JOIN `itramit_daily_desarrollo`.`formaspagoscobros` AS `Formaspagoscobro` ON (`Factura`.`FK_FORMAPAGOCOBRO` = `Formaspagoscobro`.`PK_FORMAPAGOCOBRO`) SET `Factura`.`I_COBRADO` = 165.00, `Factura`.`L_COBRADA` = 1, `Factura`.`FH_COBRO` = 2021-08-16 15:10:55, `Factura`.`S_FORMAPAGO` = tarjeta, `Factura`.`FK_FORMAPAGOCOBRO` = 41 WHERE `Factura`.`PK_FACTURA` = 166569

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your query through MySQL Workbench, I see that

```
Factura.FH_COBRO = 2021-08-16 15:10:55
```

is the cause of the syntax error. It appears that CakePHP does not add quotes around the data value.

Try:

```
'Factura.FH_COBRO' => "'" + date('Y-m-d H:i:s') + "'",
'Factura.S_FORMAPAGO' => "'tarjeta'",
```